# sh script works manually but not via cron

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mysql, cron

I have a cronjob created using this tutorial:
http://www.matt-helps.com/automatic-backup-of-mysql-database-to-s3/

It works when i run this command `sudo sh s3BucketBackupScript.sh`

But I can't get it run properly when configuring it in Cron. The script is modded with +x.

I configured it using sudo crontab -e as follows:

```
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

* * * * * /bin/sh /home/ubuntu/s3BucketBackupScript.sh
```

but no results. I think there is an empty line after the .sh lines. If I run the script without sudo it doesn't produce anything, so that's why I added it to `sudo crontab -e`.

Any hints would be very appreciated.

Comment: `* * * * *`?  What is that to suppose to do? And I myself would have used "/etc/crobtab".

Comment: run every minute as I'm testing the script?

Comment: and how long does that backup take? more then 1 minute?

Comment: no usually a second or 10 :)

Comment: can you post the content of s3BucketBackupScript.sh?

Comment: Your  `.sh` file resides in your home folder then why did you use `/bin/sh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, Do you check permission allow user run cron in file `/etc/cron.allow`. if it not have on server, you can create and add line:

```
## [root@test]# cat /etc/cron.allow
root
deploy
```

After add line ok, you can restart crond with command:

```
[root@test test]# service crond restart
```

If after change but its not run command, maybe you can use user root and add command example in `crontab -e` is:

```
* * * * * su - [user you must run command] -c "/bin/sh /home/ubuntu/s3BucketBackupScript.sh"
```

Add command ok, you should restart crond with command: `[root@test test]# service crond restart` .

I think with its maybe help you run command in crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Please do check your s3BucketBackupScript.sh script and ensure there is no relative paths given.

CRON of an individual user sets the user's home directory as `PWD`.

This may worked manually from terminal because you were in the exact directory to interpret the relative paths correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I indeed removed a few relative paths.. (I guess all of them actually). Also, should I change this line from "0 3 * * * /bin/sh /home/ubuntu/s3BucketBackupScript.sh" to "0 3 * * * /home/ubuntu/s3BucketBackupScript.sh"?

Comment: you could do like this,
0 3 * * * cd /home/ubuntu && sh s3BucketBackupScript.sh